# Mailing in MS Office word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I created set of documents by using mailing feature of word for changing some parts of documents easily. But I faced a problem about location of file from which I get data when I move documents to different file or different computer.

What can I do avoid this problem when I move documents next time?

If there is no solutions is there a way to select recipients at the same time for all documents (when there is existing data file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [relative path to a data source](http://devblog.alexsapps.com/2011/08/how-to-use-relative-path-to-data-source.html),

```
    Sub Document_Open ()
Dim PATH, SOURCE As String 
PATH = ThisDocument.Path 'determine current directory
SOURCE = PATH & "\Adresses.xls" 
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name: = Source
End Sub
```